# MySQL randomly closing connections, in old WinForms app .Net 1.1 and ODBC

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, winforms

I am having to support a very old traffic management system, developed in Winforms, Microsoft Development Environment 2003, with .Net framework 1.1, using MySQL and ODBC. The application opens 3 connections at login, and assumes those connections remain open, passing them around to various forms and class libraries.

Everything seems fine, but the database connections randomly close. Debugging this is a nightmare because I have to use a VM and don't know my way around the older versions of Visual Studio, but even so, all that debugging or the log files tell me is that the connection is closed.

I wonder if I am wasting my time trying to debug this mess. Am I looking in the wrong place? Maybe the error is on MySQL and I should be looking there. I am struggling to figure out how to approach this problem. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Here is relevant part of the log file, which tells me nothing I don't already know:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The connection is dead.
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection.ConnectionIsAlive(Exception innerException)
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection.get_State()
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection.get_IsOpen()
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection.GetDriverOdbcVersion()
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection.get_OdbcMajorVersion()
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection.get_IsV3Driver()
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteReaderObject(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand.ExecuteReader()
   at DatabaseConnection.DBConnection.ExecuteQuery(String query, DBTransaction outterTransaction)
   at DatabaseConnection.DBConnection.ExecuteQuery(String query)
   at EnigmaForms.FormMain.CheckMySQLConnection() in c:\development\nutraffic\bts client\enigmaforms\forms\formmain.cs:line 1403
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that closing other applications, including BizTalk and the SQL server agent, fixed the problem. There was also an unrelated issue (that the users treated as the same error) with a custom TCP port that wasn't opened in the NAT settings on the VM running this disasterware, although the ports were opened on the firewall.